# Node.js - верификация пользователей

Tags: node.js, jwt, аутентификация

На node.js сервере есть база данных пользователей с их статичным идентификатором.
Через клиентское приложение пользователь совершает подключение к этому серверу через сокеты с отправкой в качестве токена того самого идентификатора. Далее, на сервере, происходит сверка идентификатора между отправленным клиентом, и тем, что есть в базе. Если совпадает - сокет клиента пропускает.

При такой схеме на стороне клиента возможна подмена идентификатора, сразу пришло решение - шифровать идентификатор через секретку на стороне сервера, секретку обновлять через определенное кол-во времени, но как в таком случае быть клиенту? Высылать ему новую секретку для формирования токена на своей стороне? Тогда ведь можно и её будет "поймать" во входящем запросе на стороне клиента и сгенерировать токен, т.е. толку в такой системе никакого не будет.

Как в данном случае можно поступить? С учетом того, что единственным параметром для генерации токена может выступать лишь идентификатор пользователя.

По сути, единственное что нужно - что б пользователь не смог выполнить подключение к серверу через те же сокеты из другого места, не из клиентского приложения. В какое направление смотреть?

Comment: шифрование информации ключем асимметричного шифрования в приложении, SSL Pinning, обфускация приложения

Comment: [Криптосистема с открытым ключом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BC) просвещайтесь.

Comment: Когда вы проектируете свои схемы недокриптографии и недоавторизации, учитывайте, что информацию могут не только перехватить, подменить или просто не доставить между клиентом и сервером, но также могут прочитать на стороне хостинга вашего сервера. Почему все так уверены в надежности хостеров? Зачем нужны велосипеды с преферансом и эбонитовой свечой?